# What is a pancreatic pump?

Tags: the-expanse-2015

In episode 4 of *The Expanse*, "CQB", there is a dead man that gets examined in the morgue and they discover he has several cybernetic implants in him, one being the "pancreatic pump". What would the use be of a pancreatic pump?

> "Standard inner-ear mike, spinal stabilizer, pancreatic pump, run of the mill, for the sedentary."

Comment: Ask the next ten or so diabetics you run into. Odds are pretty good that even if none of them have insulin pumps at least one has considered getting one. Mind you, most are not embeded, but it has been done and a new embedded, closed-loop system is in clinical trials.

Comment: https://news.google.com/newspapers?nid=2209&dat=19780427&id=FpkrAAAAIBAJ&sjid=oPUFAAAAIBAJ&pg=4807,6018327&hl=en

Comment: What dmckee said. Essentially it's an artificial pancreas to prevent/cure diabetes. In a future with sufficient tech, it may be standard (either due to working better than the real pancreas, or possibly interactions due to cyborg things).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Per the wikipedia page on [artificial pancreases](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artificial_pancreas)

> The artificial pancreas is a technology in development to help people
>   with diabetes automatically control their blood glucose level by
>   providing the substitute endocrine functionality of a healthy
>   pancreas.
>
> There are several important exocrine (digestive) and endocrine
>   (hormonal) functions of the pancreas, but it is the lack of insulin
>   production which is the motivation to develop a substitute. While the
>   current state of insulin replacement therapy is appreciated for its
>   life-saving capability, the task of manually managing the blood sugar
>   level with insulin alone is arduous and inadequate.
>
> **Different approaches under consideration include:**
>
> the medical equipment approach—using an [insulin pump](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insulin_pump) under [closed loop
>   control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_theory) using real-time data from a [continuous blood glucose sensor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blood_glucose_monitoring).

The clear implication is that this individual leads a highly sedentary and presumably unhealthy lifestyle. An artificial pancreas would allow their body to remain moderately healthy and regulate diabetic control long after a real pancreas would have given up the ghost.